# C# Arbitrarily Nested List Transformation with Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I am trying to do some transformations on lists of different classes. For example, there are class A and class B.

```
class A
{
    private int Data;
    public A(int InputData)
    {
        this.Data = InputData;
    }
    public int GetData()
    {
        return this.Data;
    }
    public B ToB()
    {
        return new B(this);
    }
}

class B
{
    private double Data;
    public B(A ObjectA)
    {
        this.Data = Math.Cos(ObjectA.GetData());        //  For example
    }
    public double GetData()
    {
        return this.Data;
    }
}
```

Then, ListB1 is as the transformation result from ListA1.

```
List<A> ListA1 = new List<A>() { new A(0), new A(1), new A(2) };
List<B> ListB1 = new List<B>();
foreach (var EachItem in ListA1)
{
    ListB1.Add(EachItem.ToB());
}
```

I am wondering that is there any way to use lambda expression to perform this example? Maybe something like `List<B> ListB1 = ListA1.ConvertAll(ObjectA => { ObjectA.ToB(); });` However, it seems that the input parameter of `ConvertAll` method is designed as a Converter object, not lambda expression. Moreover, is there any easy way to deal with arbitrarily nested list cases, such as the following ListA2? I know that ListB2 could be generated by nested foreach loop, but I am looking forward to find a way like `List<List<B>> ListB2 = ListA2.ConvertAll(ObjectA => { ObjectA.ToB(); });`. Then the same structure could be applied to arbitrarily nested list.

```
List<List<A>> ListA2 = new List<List<A>>();
ListA2.Add(ListA1);
ListA2.Add(ListA1);
List<List<B>> ListB2 = new List<List<B>>();
foreach (var EachItem1 in ListA2)
{
    List<B> temp = new List<B>();
    foreach (var EachItem2 in EachItem1)
    {
        temp.Add(EachItem2.ToB());
    }
    ListB2.Add(temp);
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do Something like

```
ListA2.ForEach(x => x.ToB()).ToList();
```

That way you now have a list of B

Comment: It seems not work because the return value of method `ForEach` is void. `.ToList()` cannot be concatenated after `ForEach` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq's `Select` to translate each item;

```cs
List<B> ListB1 = ListA1.Select(a => a.ToB()).ToList();
List<List<B>> ListB2 = ListA2.Select(a2 => a2.Select(a => a.ToB()).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: The `Select` method seems a kind of solution. However, when it comes to the case `List<...List<A>>`, the nested Select structure is also needed.